# I can't paint boldy onto this model even after testing other settings and whenever I paint it give light streaks

Tags: modeling

[image]

can you please find a solution or help me with this problem.

Comment: Hello could you please pack your image (File > External Data > Pack Resources) and share the object (not the rest of your scene): https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: https://pasteall.org/media/9/6/96c23a484d0c07bd0f14189c9d344915.blend1                                                                             I uploaded it into there pastel.org/blend

Comment: @moonboots look at the comment above !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have overlapping vertices, select all in *Edit* mode and press <kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge by Distance*.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was honestly struggling and you helped very easily